# Special characters problem in NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ipad

My NSPredicate argument contains some special characters like single parentless. When it is executed, exception is thrown.

How to deal with special characters when using NSPredicate ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you strip those characters out? If the search will still work that is the easiest thing.